# C++ i can`t understand why it call "father class static function" and it call just father destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, destructor

I have next code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A() { cout << "A() ";}
    virtual void f()=0;
    virtual void g() { cout << "ag() ";}
    static void h() { cout << "ah() ";}
    void i() { cout << "ai() ";}
    ~A() { cout << "~A() "; }
};

class B: public A{
    void f() { cout << "bf() ";}
public:
    void g() { cout << "bg() ";}
};

class C: public B{
public:
    static void h() { cout << "ch() "; }
    void g() { cout << "cg() ";}
    ~C() { cout << "~C() ";}
};

void f1(){
    B b;
    C c;
    b.h();
    c.h();  
    A* arr[2] = { new B ,new C};
    arr[0]->h();
    arr[1]->h();
    delete arr[0];
    delete arr[1];
}


int main(){
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why it prints A() A() ah() ch() A() A() ah() ah() ~A() ~A() ~C() ~A() ~A() and it doesn't print A() A() ah() ch() A() A() ah() ch() ~A() ~A() ~C() ~A() ~C(). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like about 90% of this code (and 90% of the output) has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: TL;DR: destructors should be virtual, static functions cannot be virtual.

Comment: Respect the time of people helping you here and spend a little bit of time removing the parts you do *not* find confusing before asking about the rest.

Comment: I'm sorry for bad question. I'm new on stackoverflow. I will try to not repeat my fault.

Comment: "_I can't understand why_" is how you don't ask questions (on SO or elsewhere). You should **explain why you believe your code has well defined behavior and what this behavior should be**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you forgot to declare the destructor of `A` virtual. Because of this, deleting a derived object through an `A` pointer has undefined behaviour. One possible outcome of undefined behaviour is that `~C()` is not printed (and also that memory was leaked). A decent compiler would have warned you of this unless you had forgot to enable warnings.

Solution: Don't delete the objects through a base class pointer, or make the destructor of base class virtual.

Secondly, `ch()` is not printed when you call `arr[0]->h()` because the static type of `arr[0]` is not `C*`, but `A*`. Virtual dispatch is not used because the function is not virtual. And it cannot be virtual because it's a static member function. Static member functions cannot be overridden.

Solution: Adjust your expectations.

Comment: I`m preparing for exam and i tried to solve some subject. Teacher give us some code examples and we need to write what the code are doing. You said that arr[0] is A* type so i ask why it call A and C destructor too for arr[1]?

Comment: Do you mean that `delete arr[1];` would call both `A` and `C` destructor? Well, that's not what you see in the output. Pay more attention to which output comes from which statement. Step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: I understood. ~C() and ~A() is from `C c` destructor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `arr` is an array that contains pointers to `A` class instances.

Therefore, invoking `arr[0]->h()` invokes `A::h()`. `h()` is not a virtual class method. You obviously understand how virtual inheritance works and how virtual functions override their base class versions. However, for virtual inheritance to work, the function must actually be declared with the `virtual` keyword. You don't see the `virtual` keyword used to declare the `h()` class method, do you, so why do you expect `h()` to work like a virtual function?

In fact, because `h()` is actually a `static` class function, then

```
arr[0]->h();
arr[1]->h();
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
A::h();
A::h();
```

The compiler does not even bother to compile the code that retrieves the `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` pointers, because they are irrelevant. `this` is not used by `static` class methods, of course, so there's no need to waste time figuring out what `this` should be.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am addressing the specific point cited, that the actual output is "...ah() ah()..." instead of what OP expects, which is "...ah() ch()...".